# Ionic2 + Dominant/Average Color

Tags: angular, colors, ionic2

Trying to get a dominant/average color of a profile image and use it as the background of the page in an Ionic2 / Angular2 app.

Have tried Colorify.js, node-vibrant.js, Dominant-color.js and a few more...firstly, are there any tried and tested libraries that work (with some sample code if possible) ?

Else, below is the snippet of my implementation of node-vibrant.js (node-vibrant) which is throwing an error

```
var vibrant = new Vibrant(JSON.stringify(this.user.attachments.profileImage));
vibrant.getPalette(swatches => {
  for(var swatch in swatches) {
    if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch]) {
      console.log("Swatches: " + swatch);
    }
  }
});
```

The error/output I get is various depending on my limited coding skills...sometimes the swatches[swatch] is {}, sometimes swatches is printing just the text "raw", and sometimes I'm getting a cyclic code error.

Any direction would be much appreciated.